# IIS Management User Login Fails on 7.5 / Works on 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, iis-8.5, iis-manager

I have a small, simple ASP.Net 4.5.2 Web App for which access is restricted by IIS Manager Users. The parent site is public (Allow Anon / All Users) and the app has all authentication disabled and the IIS User added at server level, and under IIS Authorization Rules as seen in the config below. This works perfectly on IIS 8.5, but the login fails on 7.5 with 401 Unauthorized.

I've combed through the role features and site and server and app settings and I can't find a difference between the two, other than 7.5 on Win Server 2008 vs. 8.5 on Win Server 2012-R2. Both have IIS Management Service running with Windows and IIS Manager Users selected, and the Enable remote connections unchecked (only using it for app access, not administration). Both are using the ASP.Net 4.0 App pool under Network Service, who has full rights to the web folder structures on both servers.

Ideas on what to look for would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet" />
                <add name="HttpPost" />
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add verb="GET,POST" name="About" type="MyApp.About" path="About" />
        </handlers>

        <modules>
            <!-- Replaces Global.asax -->
            <add name="AppModule" type="MyApp.AppModule" />
            <!-- Required for IIS Manager Users to browse the site -->
            <add name="WebManagementBasicAuthentication" type="Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebManagementBasicAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </modules>

        <defaultDocument enabled="false">
            <files>
                <clear />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

        <security>
            <authorization>
                <clear />
                <remove users="*" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="IIS.Manager.Username.Here" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that on the newly spun up 2008 / IIS 7.5 server `Network Service` didn't have `Read` permissions to `c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\`.